# How to guarantee a webpage will look uniform throughout different browsers?

Tags: html, css

Without having to view it in different browsers. Is it possible to ensure a webpage will look exactly the same in different browsers? Desktop only not tablets or smartphones.

If I set pixel width and height on every single div and table will is this be enough to ensure it will look identical?

Comment: Why do you want to? It's unlikely to be necessary, in my experience...

Comment: But I've noticed this is to be the case. Even within the same browser but different versions the page does not look the same, I think it's mostly due to CSS. But what if I enforce the width and height within the element? Like Old School HTML width=".." height=".." ?

Comment: But why do you *want* to? Designing web pages is a different paradigm to designing leaflets in DTP software.

Comment: Develop with firefox, but test all with ie, ff, opera, chrome and safari. There is no guarancy, but in modern times there is only a little effort for the crossbrowser finetuning needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple answer: No.**

If you [validate your code using W3](http://validator.w3.org/) in theory it should be the same on any browser - in practice you need to test it.

It depends how complex your HTML/CSS is, if it is very simple then you are likely to be ok, if you are using things such as text shadows then no you will need to test on a variety of browsers.

Out of interest why don't you want to check on multiple browsers - it should only take you a few extra moments?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools like http://browsershots.org/ where you can test a lot of browsers in just one step. So you don#t need to install all of them. But no guarantee that the website really looks like that, I never used them to really make a browser test.

But programmatically there is just no way to make a website that will defenitely look the same everywhere. In general you can say: the more complex your markup and css are, the more problems you will get. Despite IE 6 with it's broken box model, all of them are able to display the standard stuff quite correct. But the less flexible, the more complex your design gets, the more problems you will have with different (especially old) browsers. I would suggest keeping it as flexible as possible (avoid position:absolute if not really needed for example). So maybe your text hase one line more or less in different browsers but it just doesn't matter.